# Pandas Dataframe: df.apply ignore error rows

Tags: python, pandas, apply, string-to-datetime

Good morning! I am trying to convert a column that has multiple dates in various formats into a datetime column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'c1':['2020/10/01','10/01/2020','10/1/2020','31/08/2020','12-21-2020','5-3-2020','05-03-2020','ERRER']    
}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['c1'])
```

The code above creates my dataframe to test on. If I run the following code, I get an error because 'ERRER' is not a valid date:

```
df['c2'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['c1']), axis=1)
```

Is there a way to skip a row in the apply function if it can't be converted to a datetime? Or convert error rows to a default date (i.e. '1900-01-01')?

Answer (score 2):

If use `errors='coerce'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) get `NaT` (missing values for datetimes) if not datetime-like values - yoou can pass column for improve performance, not `apply` for looping:

```
df['c2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['c1'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
           c1         c2
0  2020/10/01 2020-10-01
1  10/01/2020 2020-10-01
2   10/1/2020 2020-10-01
3  31/08/2020 2020-08-31
4  12-21-2020 2020-12-21
5    5-3-2020 2020-05-03
6  05-03-2020 2020-05-03
7       ERRER        NaT
```

Then remove rows with `NaT`s by column `c2`:

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['c2'])
print (df1)
           c1         c2
0  2020/10/01 2020-10-01
1  10/01/2020 2020-10-01
2   10/1/2020 2020-10-01
3  31/08/2020 2020-08-31
4  12-21-2020 2020-12-21
5    5-3-2020 2020-05-03
6  05-03-2020 2020-05-03
```

Or you can replace them to some datetime (not string `'1900-01-01'`):

```
df['c2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['c1'], errors='coerce').fillna(pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01'))
print (df)
           c1         c2
0  2020/10/01 2020-10-01
1  10/01/2020 2020-10-01
2   10/1/2020 2020-10-01
3  31/08/2020 2020-08-31
4  12-21-2020 2020-12-21
5    5-3-2020 2020-05-03
6  05-03-2020 2020-05-03
7       ERRER 1900-01-01

print (df.dtypes)
c1            object
c2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I was looking for and takes it one step further. Its always the simple solutions that seem to be the best.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `errors` with `coerce`, for the one cannot convert will return `NaT`

```
df['c2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['c1'], errors='coerce')
df
Out[76]: 
           c1         c2
0  2020/10/01 2020-10-01
1  10/01/2020 2020-10-01
2   10/1/2020 2020-10-01
3  31/08/2020 2020-08-31
4  12-21-2020 2020-12-21
5    5-3-2020 2020-05-03
6  05-03-2020 2020-05-03
7       ERRER        NaT
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I was looking for. Its always the simple solutions that seem to be the best.

Comment: @NLMDEJ yw happy coding ~

Answer (score 1):

You may want to convert ERRER beforehand using `replace`. This means that other rows with missing values NaT will remain NaT.

```
df['c1'] = df['c1'].replace('ERRER', '01/01/1900')
```

After that it should work:

```
df['c2'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['c1']), axis=1)
```